# How to select a default option using thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a drop down like following,

```
<select id="role" class="form-control" th:field="*{role}" >


    <option th:field="*{role}"  value="USER">USER</option>
    <option selected th:field="*{role}" value="ADMIN" >ADMIN</option>
    <option th:field="*{role}" value="SUPERUSER">SUPERUSER</option>


 </select>
```

I want default option as ADMIN. For that i added selected inside option tag. but default option still pointing to USER. Can anyone help me o solve this. Thanks

Comment: Adding only `selected` attribute without a value is not valid Thymeleaf syntax, try using `selected="selected"`.

Comment: i tried it already. not helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the value of "role" to "ADMIN" in your controller (in the java), before the page is rendered.

Also, you don't need all those extra th:field attributes.  th:field should only appear on the select.

```
<select id="role" class="form-control" th:field="*{role}" >
    <option value="USER">USER</option>
    <option value="ADMIN" >ADMIN</option>
    <option value="SUPERUSER">SUPERUSER</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like following to get it working.

```
 <script th:inline="javascript">
            /*<![CDATA[*/
        window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            var optionSelected = [[${product.role}]];
            if(optionSelected == null){
                $("#role").val("ADMIN");
            } 

        });
        /*]]>*/
    </script>
```

and removed the selected attribute from the option.

Comment: To be honest, that's a pretty ugly solution. `selected` should work. Verify that the `selected` attribute is still there in the rendered HTML page.

Comment: I'am not seeing selected attribute if i use selected inside option tag. It would be better if you explain why it is a bad solution .

Comment: @sparrow the right solution is the response of Metroids